# Print UART-message (up to 3 digits): Problem with atoi()?

Tags: uart

I want to display an up to 3 digit number received via the UART communication protocol from my PC to the MUC. UART initialization, enabling global interrupt and display-function to display an integer of up to 3 digits on the 7-segment-display is done and functioning, when for example trying out:

```
segment_num(111); //for a int number=111
```

the number is shown correctly on the 7-digit-displays.

My setting on Hterm are the following (using ASC and CR, trying out to send a '222'):

[image: Hterm settings, trying out to send '222']

My ISR is as followed:

```
ISR(USART1_RX_vect) {
    static char buffer[4]; // 3 digits + CR terminator
    static uint8_t i = 0;

    char received_char = UDR1;
    if (received_char == '\r') {
        buffer[i] = '\r';
        int number = atoi(buffer);
        segment_num(number);
        _delay_ms(100);
        i = 0;
        } 
    else {
        segment_num(333);
        _delay_ms(100);
        buffer[i] = received_char;
        i++;
        if (i >= 4) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

While `segment_num(333);` is for debugging reasons as to see if it enters the 'else' state when the correct number isn't shown when the if-condition isn't met.

Unfortunately I am missing out on something or the char-payload isn't transformed correctly into an int to be displayed correctly. But because it doesn't even enter the if-condition, something must be off with my settings in Hterm and the if-requirement.

Would be really glad if someone could help out, trying to get it right for the last 3 hours. ;)

Changed settings in Hterm to CR+LF and DEC instead of ASC. Didn't help either. Which from my understanding it also shouldn't, since '/r' with CR should be correct.

Comment: You're probably just missing incoming characters due to the delays in your interrupt handler.  ANY delay in an ISR is generally a bad idea, it's just going to cause other interrupts to be missed.

Comment: Even without the delay it is going to the else statement and ignoring the if-condition.